# Waffle package: Colors mixed up with a Zero/0 in data

Tags: r, ggplot2, waffle-chart

An example from my data:

```
1 99
85 15
8 92
1 99
10 90
0 100
```

The problem is the last set of numbers: When there is a 0 included, waffle behaves like it's a 100. The zero seems to be ignored. Is there a way to prevent this?

Working: Green = 10, orange = 90

```
waffle(c(10, 90))
```

[image]

Not working: Green = 0, but its visualized as Green = 100. Every rectangle should be orange

```
waffle(c(0, 100))
```

[image]

Comment: I am guessing it is picking a preset colour to plot, in first plot you have 2 categories, so start with green then red, in second one there is nothing to plot for the first one, so it picks green for the second one. Maybe you should supply colours manually.

Comment: I did, problem remains the same

Comment: Yes, I would say it is a bug, and noticed your bug report. @hrbrmstr is the author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Danke for finding this and filing the issue! Fixed in 0.6.0.9000:

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(
  waffle(c(thing1=0, thing2=100), rows=5),  
  waffle(c(thing1=25, thing2=75), rows=5)
)
```

[image]

Comment: Danke for prompt fix and response!

Comment: Bitte! Thanks for the quick fix.